# css dropdown menu will not stay open on hover

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

hi guys really need help, my dropdown menu wont stay visible on hover, this may not be working because i have the drop menu itself set out as table column and set to a min-width of 900px rather than it being the same width as its parent but its the only way i could make a larger dropdown than one column width.

My html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>



<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>title</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="global.css" type="text/css">

</head>
 <body id="body">
  
  <div class="wrap">
  
 <nav align="center">
  <ul id="ul">
   <li id="ulli"><a id="ullia" href="?page=home">home</a></li>
   <li id="ulli"><a id="ullia" href="?page=pests">pests</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a class="subhead">insects</a></li>
     <li><a class="sub" href="?page=ants">ants</a></li>
     <li><a class="sub" href="?page=b_bugs">bed bugs</a></li>
     <li><a class="sub" href="?page=bees">bees</a></li>
     <li><a class="sub" href="?page=c_roaches">cockroaches</a></li>
     <li><a class="sub" href="?page=fleas">fleas</a></li>
     <li><a class="sub" href="?page=flies">flies</a></li>
     <li><a class="sub" href="?page=moths">moths</a></li>
     <li><a class="sub" href="?page=mos">mosquitoes & Midges</a></li>
     <li><a class="sub" href="?page=sil">silverfish</a></li>
     <li><a class="sub" href="?page=spiders">spiders</a></li>
     <li><a class="sub" href="?page=wasps">wasps</a></li>
     <li><a class="sub" href="?page=w_worm">woodworm</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li id="ulli"><a id="ullia" href="?page=pests">maintenance</a></li>
   <li id="ulli"><a id="ullia" href="?page=pests">about</a></li>
   <li id="ulli"><a id="ullia" href="?page=pests">contact us</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
   
   
   <div class="header_bg" align="center">
    <div align="center" class="header">
     <div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   
  </div>
 
 </body>
</html>
```

and my css.

```html
#body {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
 }

.wrap {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
 }
 

 
nav {
 width:100%;
 min-width:1000px;
 height:72px;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 float:left;
 background-image:url("images/nav_bg.jpg");
 z-index:4;
 }
 
#ul {
 max-width:180px;
 width:14.9%;
 text-align:center;
 display:inline;
 list-style:none;
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px 0px 0px 0;
 z-index:4;
 }
 
#ulli {
 width:180px;
 margin-top:24px;
 position:relative;
 display:inline-block;
 }
 
#ullia {
 list-style:none;
 font-family:calibri, arial;
 font-size:22px;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#fff;
 padding:20px;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
     -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
      -o-transition: all 0.3s;
         transition: all 0.3s;
 }
 
#ullia:hover {
 text-shadow:2px 2px 80px #fff;
 }
 
nav li ul {
 width:75%;
 min-width:900px;
 height:0px;
 top:20px;
 display:table-column;
 background: #fff;
 position:absolute;
 float:left;
 left:-100%;
 text-align:left;
 overflow:hidden;
 border-bottom-left-radius:7px;
 border-bottom-right-radius:7px;
 padding-top:34px;
 padding-bottom:24px;
 -webkit-column-count:3;
    -moz-column-count:3;
     -ms-column-count:3;
   -o-column-count:3;
         column-count:3;
 -webkit-column-width:150px;
    -moz-column-width:150px;
     -ms-column-width:150px;
   -o-column-width:150px;
         column-width:150px;
 -webkit-column-rule:1px dotted #999;
    -moz-column-rule:1px dotted #999;
     -ms-column-rule:1px dotted #999;
   -o-column-rule:1px dotted #999;
      column-rule:1px dotted #999;
  -webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 6px #999;
     -moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 6px #999;
      -ms-box-shadow:1px 1px 6px #999;
       -o-box-shadow:1px 1px 6px #999;
          box-shadow:1px 1px 6px #999;
 visibility:hidden;
 z-index:-1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
         -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
          -o-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
             transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
 }
 
nav li:hover ul {
 position:absolute;
 top:20px;
 opacity:1;
 height:183px;
 visibility:visible;
 }
 
.subhead {
 height:20px;
 padding-bottom:15px;
 font-family:calibri, arial;
 font-size:22px;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 color:#454545;
 }
 
.sub {
 padding-bottom:15px;
 font-family:calibri, arial;
 font-size:18px;
 text-transform:capitalize;
 color:#454545;
 list-style:none;
 text-decoration:none;
 padding-right:35px;
 }
 
.header_bg {
 width:100%;
 min-width:1000px;
 height:261px;
 float:top;
 top:72px;
 position:relative;
 background-image:url("images/header_bgr.jpg");
 z-index:-2;
 }
 
.header {
 width:1000px;
 min-width:1000px;
 height:261px;
 top:72px;
 position:initial;
 background-image:url("images/header.jpg");
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position:center;
 }
```

Comment: Major problem I notice off the bat is you're using the same ID multiple times. ID's have to be unique. You should change them to classes.

Answer (score 1):

This is the basic concept of dropdown menu:

```
  li ul {display: none;} /*to hide the sub menu*/
  li:hover > ul {display: block;} /*to display the sub menu when on Hover */
```

Based on your code, you should do this then:

**Add this:**

```
li:hover>#ulli ul{
    display: block;
}
```

**UPDATED:**

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/psym3oqc/1/)**

if it looks to collide the main menu as in your code below:

```
nav li:hover ul {
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    opacity:1;
    height:183px;
    visibility:visible;
}
```

change `top:20px;` into `top:40px;` for instance. this will correct the appearance.

**UPDATED 2:**

Besides, link for Insect without href!
Here's the final **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/alicera/ru93d24v/2/)**

Comment: that still does not work, if i delete the dropdown animation and have it displayed open when i load the page the <a> tags don't even act like hyperlinks in the dropdown. Its as if whatever is in the dropdown doesn't exist, i have tried padding the links could it be to do with z-index?

Comment: ok so i have left it open and played about with it, the only links that work are the very bottom two so is something sitting in front of them that i have looked past?

Comment: wait pls, my internet connection runs as a snail.

Comment: I update my answer and all links and appearance looks sweet now. pls let me know